# Alert disappears by itself in the http response without waiting for the user to click on ok

Tags: angular

If I put the alert anywhere else it waits for the user to click on ok but inside the response it shows for 1 second and then vanishes by itself.

```
       this.data.sendContactForm(userDetail).subscribe((res: any)=>{
            this.contactForm.reset();
            this.contactForm.markAsUntouched();
            this.submitted = false;
            this.contactForm.controls.service.setValue("");
            grecaptcha.reset();
            this.captchaResponse = false;
            this.loading = false;
            alert("Success");
        },(err)=>{
          this.loading = false;
        });
```

Comment: Is there any error on console?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want it to show for one second and then vanish by itself, or at the moment, it shows for one second and vanishes?

Comment: no error, I want it to stay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your page is getting refreshed again because of these lines

```
grecaptcha.reset();
 this.captchaResponse = false;
 this.loading = false;
```

Comment: You are right When i place the alert before `grecaptcha.reset();` the alert stays. The statement it there because it refreshes the google reCaptcha. This is in my index.html which makes it work`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>`  How is `grecaptcha.reset()` doing that.